# How to increment a specific amount of features

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, features

I current have attribute bar all empty with null values.
I would like to fill that attribute starting from 10001, adding +1 to each of the features and having N before the number

So far I have come up with this.

```
'N'+to_string(1000+1)
```

This is only giving N10001 to all features.
How can I tell it that it needs to go alongside the column and increment it from the value the feature above has?

I have another attribute that could be used for comparison, attribute object id already has a number sequence for all those null features.

Comment: Sorry, I am using QGIS 3.10.8-A Coruña

I would like to update the attribute 'Bar' with an expression if possible, no plugins.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

`'N1000'||to_string($id+1)` should do what you are looking for. Since the ID starts out with `0`, we need to add `+1` in order to start with `N10001`.

Comment: I used it but got an error saying:

"An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string:
Cannot convert 'N10008895' to double"

Comment: Since `N` is no number, but a string, you chose the wrong field type, I guess.

Comment: I am using a template, I can't change they field types, the field is of the type Qstring, that's why I was thinking of converting it to string in the end of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

To extend [@Eriks answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/394029/107424): just in case your ID's do not start with 1, you can use this expression:

```
'N' || to_string(10000 + array_find(array_agg($id),$id) + 1)
```

It will always start at 10001, no matter what your actual ID values are.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it's giving me some random numbers, I guess the id values have something to do with it.

I got 1234, then 2474, all random numbers

Comment: Shouldnt be random, as array_find() returns the index of the current ID in the array. The only reason I can think of, why it may appear random to you, is the sorting of your attribute table, which probably is not sorted by feature ids.

Comment: Well I do have a filter in place, I don't know if that is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a PyQGIS solution:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # choose the layer to edit
fieldname = 'mycolumn' # name of the column to change
i = 10001 # value to start counting at

# no changes needed below #

# start edit mode of the layer
with edit(layer):
    # add the new field
    # layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(fieldname, QVariant.String)])
    # layer.updateFields()
    # loop through features
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        # change value of the new field to "Nxxxxx"
        feature[fieldname] = 'N' + str(i)
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
        # increase counter
        i += 1
```

Comment: That worked well thank you.

Could you tell me why you made a new field tho? Would it be harder to do the changes in a existing attribute?